# How to pass jquery range selector value to controller as min and max value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using 2 text boxes to get range from user. I've to two variables

```
 public int x_min {get;set;}
 public int x_max {get;set;}
```

on UI I use

```
editorfor ( x => x.x_min) and editorfor( x => x.x_max)
```

I saw demo on http://jqueryui.com/slider/ that is

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
```

But they are using body and head tag, which I am not sure how to use on mvc view. and I can't see where to get those values and how can I pass it to the server on post? I have almost 10 range selectors and 10 check boxes

Comment: You need a property to bind to and generate a form control for it (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number)`), then apply the plugin to it - `$('#Number').slider({ .... });`

Comment: It sounds good, but I am not sure how to implement that ?  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(); so Instead of slider I should use number ? and what'll be inside the {...} ?

Comment: You just replace `#slider` with whatever the `id` of your textbox is. And inside the `{..}` you just add whatever options you want (include `min` and `max` values - its all in the documentation.

Comment: Or were you looking to use something like [this slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)?

Comment: Exactly! I want such thing, and I want to hold those two values and pass them to the server

Comment: How do I pass those two values to x_min and x_max? for processing them further

Comment: But Jquery UI comes with lots problems in css

Comment: Look at the demo I linked to. - handle the `slide: function( event, ui )` and set the values of your textboxes using javascript (`ui.values[0]` is the `min` and `ui.values[1]` is the `max`). And what make you think there a problems with the css?

Comment: Thanks buddy, It says disturbs whole css of my view, it loads everything on whole page. It's okay. I'll make changes in the css :)

Comment: It's not relevant to this thread but I want to ask you, I am trying to display search result on the same page on the submit, I used jquery ajax, I am getting proper result set but I don't know how to update result on the same page, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: If you wish, we can chat too, I'll post my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110787/discussion-between-nil-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: And I should replace #slider-range in "  $("#slider-range").slider({ " with?

Comment: Is it fine if I have int x_min and int x_max values? or do I need to replace it with array or something ?

Comment: `int x_min` and `int x_max` will be fine (you can call them what ever you want). Just use the exact same code in the demo (including `<div id="slider-range"></div>` but change `slide: function( event, ui ) { $('#x_min),val(ui.values[0]); $('#x_max),val(ui.values[1]); }`

Comment: It gives an error for x_max called ')' I fixed it then it says un  terminated string constant

Comment: sorry, missed the `'` after `$('#x_min')` (ditto for `$('#x_max')`)

Comment: In script debug it says " Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slider' "

Comment: Then you have not included the correct scripts

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Now copy pasted everything, still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want single slider for minimum and maximum values, then you need a range slider (refer [demo](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)) which has two handles for the values and in the `.slide()` event, update the values of the textboxes.

Your html should be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.x_min, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.x_max, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

and the script

```
$('#slider-range').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ @Model.x_min, @Model.x_max ], // assumes you are setting these in the controller
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#x_min').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#x_max').val(ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/adR6aU) for a working example.

Comment: I'll check out DotNetFiddle as in, this thing isn't working, it isn't showing any range selector on the UI

Comment: What do you mean? Is showing a range of 0 to 500 (those are `min` and `max` options in the range slider), and when you slide the handles, the values in you textboxes update!

Comment: It's working now! I fixed it, it was a silly mistake I added jquery twice! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I want to repeat this thing for 10 range selectors, What could be the most logical way to do that ?

Comment: Rather that having 20 properties, you could have a view model with 2 properties and return a collection contain 10 of them. Then you would have 10 `<div>` elements all with the same class name and use `$('.slider-range').slider({` but you would need relative selectors to update the textboxes. No time now but I will update the fiddle later (maybe an hour or 2)

Comment: Found some time. I have forked the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pA1eqp)

Comment: Oops, dude thanks a lot but, I have all diff range selectors. I'll try to make something to  work from your code. Can I display those selected range into the labels and hide the text boxes ?

Comment: Do you mean they are not all in the range (say) 0 to 500?. If so then just add 2 more properties to your view model for the `MinRange` and `MaxRange` and instead of hardcoding then, set them from the view model (just as the fiddle does for the min and max values of the handles

Comment: Na na, I mean, there are range selectors for performance, year, calmar ratio everything have diff ranges, there are float ranges as well, I hope, it'll work fine for float variables as well

Comment: It seems you're busy today, I had another question :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110870/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nil).

Comment: How can I expand it's range ? It always shows between 0 -100 even if I set it to -50 to 200 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can set the range to whatever you want. See the [updated DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pA1eqp) where the range extents are set in the controller